# Deploying redis on Heroku when manually precompiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redis, asset-pipeline

I'm following the instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo to deploy redis on Heroku. I'm however running into some issues while manually precompiling my assets on localhost using:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

before pushing it out to heroku. The ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] config variable isn't set when I'm doing the production mode precompile on localhost so I get an URI error when URI.parse is called.

How do I get around this error? I don't want to hardcode the URI in my production.rb since Heroku sets this when starting the redis server. I'm quite new to this whole asset pipeline / deployment processes so any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In application.rb, I set the following to prevent initialization prior to Redis starting up:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: This was removed in Rails 4 :( - Any solution for newer version of Rails?